# How to add new hidden HTML with best performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large block of HTML that needs to be replaced, which includes `fadeOut`/`fadeIn` transitions. I can't figure out how to add the HTML to the page (hidden) without wrapping it in a div.

```
$.get('/ajax', function(newHtml){
    var $newEvent = $('<div class="new-event" />').hide().html(newHtml);
    $('#content .event').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove(); //old event
        $newEvent.appendTo('#content').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('new-event'); //then remove the wrapper div that I didnt need in the first place
    });
});
```

What is the best way to do this while utilizing best practices for performance?

### Solution:

For some reason, I thought that creating a new element like this: `$(newHtml)` was less efficient (bad performance) than `html(newHtml)`. But apparently, they are the same as far as performance goes (I have no data to back this up other than my own observations).

So the following code is just as efficient as the previous:

```
$.get('/ajax', function(newHtml){
    var $newEvent = $(newHtml).hide();
    $('#content .event').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove(); //old event
        $newEvent.appendTo('#content').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: If you already have the HTML as a long string of code, I don't think there are any issues. AFAIK, The performance problems arise when you're adding new stuff to the DOM over and over again, dozens or hundreds of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the code to the page, have top level elements all be hidden

```
<div style="display:none;">...</div>
```

When `fadeIn` is called jQuery automatically removes it for you.

If you can't modify the returned html just do it this way then,

```
$(newHtml).hide().appendTo('#content');
```

That will hide it before being added to the DOM.

Comment: the html being returned from the ajax request is not already hidden, so I need to hide it manually (either by wrapping it in a div with display:none, or calling the jQuery hide() function, which I am already doing)

Comment: Hmm...I tried this already, and thought for some reason that this was causing performance issues for me. The animation was not smooth at all. But it must have been something else causing my performance issues because I see no problems now. I guess the simplest solution is the best!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
$('#content .event').fadeOut('slow', function()
{
    $(this).html(newHtml).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: That won't work because it will be populating the contents of the `.event` with another `.event`. Basically, I need to replace `.event` with the new `.event`

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/hHmkE/2/ for a working alternative, which should work as you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't simply replace the content of `.event` instead of removing it and creating a new one?

```
$.get( '/ajax', function( newHtml )
{
    $( '#content .event' ).fadeOut( 'slow', function ()
    {
        $( this ).html( newHtml ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
    });
});
```

Edit

If you really need to remove the entire node, you can do this instead

```
$( this ).remove();
$( '<div class="new-event">' ).appendTo( $('#content') ).html( newHtml ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
```

Comment: That won't work because it will be populating the contents of the `.event` with another `.event`. Basically, I need to replace `.event` with the new `.event`

Comment: With this code, the content of .event will be replaced with the new one. Is this not what you want?

Comment: He needs to replace `.event` itself, as well as its content.

Comment: The question is about replacing a large block of HTML, it doesn't specify if the element also needs to be removed. Anyway added an alternative to replace the old event node with the new one.

Comment: Your answer is now identical to the code sample that I provided in the very beginning. =/

Comment: Do your "new html" provide a node element already? I supposed yes, and that's my first answer. If not, my second answer will create it for you. So what do you need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could just have it as a javascript string, and add it when you need.

```
var $newEvent = $(newHtml);
// and later on
$( '#content .event' ).fadeOut('slow', function ()
{
    $(this).append($newEvent).fadeIn( 'slow' );
});
```

Comment: That won't work because it will be populating the contents of the `.event` with another `.event`. Basically, I need to replace `.event` with the new `.event`